# Can't get data from service in Angular 2

Tags: angular

This is simple shopping cart application with Rails API. I have items in my ShowComponent with addToCart button and CartComponent. I have CartService with main Cart functions.
Here is my cart.service:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Item}       from './cart/cart';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

  private cartItems:Item[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  getCart() {
    return this.cartItems;
  }

  addToCart(pizza, qtyString:string = "1") {
    let qty = Number(qtyString);
    console.log(typeof qty, qty);
    console.log(typeof pizza, pizza);
    if (this.cartItems.length == 0) {
      this.cartItems.push(new Item(pizza['title'], pizza['price'], qty));
      console.log(this.cartItems);
    } else {
      for(let i = 0; i < this.cartItems.length; i++) {
        if (this.cartItems[i].title == pizza.title) {
            console.log(this.cartItems[i].qty);
          this.cartItems[i].qty += qty;
          return true;
        };
      }
      this.cartItems.push(new Item(pizza.title, pizza.price, qty));
    }
  }

  deleteItems(pizza) {
    this.cartItems.splice(this.cartItems.indexOf(pizza), 1);
  }
  editItems(value, i) {
    this.cartItems[i].qty = +value;
  }
}
```

I use addToCart function in my show.component.html to add items and all work fine (I have object with all data in result). But when I try to go to Cart, I can't get this data (this.cartItems.length == 0). Here is my CartComponent:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CartService}       from '../cart.service';
import {Pizza}             from '../pizza';
import {Item}              from './cart';
import {Router}            from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId:    module.id,
  selector:    'app-cart',
  templateUrl: 'cart.component.html',
  styleUrls:   ['cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    cartItems = [];

  constructor(private cartService: CartService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartItems = this.cartService.getCart();
    console.log(this.cartItems.length);
  }

  getTotalPrice() {
    let total = 0;
    this.cartItems.forEach((pizza: any, i:number) => {
      total += pizza.price * pizza.qty;
    })
    return total;
  }
}
```

Here is my Item model:

```js
export class Item {
  constructor(public title:string, public price:number, public qty:number) {}
}
```

What should I do to get it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You code has no declaration of providers to let Angular know how to instantiate CartService. The simplest fix would be to add this to your CartComponent's decorator @Component:

`providers: [CartService]`

But you need to decide what's the best place to add providers based on your app logic. This can be done on the component, on its parents, or on the app level (in the @NgModule decorator).

Keep in mind that if you declare the provider on the component level, a new instance of CartService will be created each tim you create CartComponent (e.g. navigate to the cart route, go back, navigate again would create 2 instances). Since your code initializes the array with cart items with [], its content will be erased whenever the new instance of the CartComponent is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Provider was added to the AppComponent:            `import {CartService}       from './cart.service';`

`@Component({
  providers:   [PizzaService, CartService]
})`

`export class AppComponent {}`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd save your data to the back end (via an HTTP request) and then retrieve it on the "show" page.